# How to minimize\plan ahead the effect of running sp_delete_backuphistory? Measure the gains too!

Tags: sql-server, backup, delete, scripting, monitoring

while running the following query:

```
-- DATEADD (datepart , number , date )  

DECLARE @dt DATETIME
SELECT @dt = DATEADD(month,-6,getdate())
select @dt
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_backuphistory @oldest_date = @dt
```

I get lots of locks and blocks, possibly because this command has not been run for a while, if ever.

[image]

Is there a way to find out how much is there to delete in each of the involved tables, before I actually run or plan to run this command?

I use [dateadd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to calculate 6 months.

Within [sp_delete_backuphistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-backuphistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the following tables are trimmed:

> sp_delete_backuphistory must be run from the msdb database and affects
>   the following tables:
>
> backupfile
>
> backupfilegroup
>
> backupmediafamily
>
> backupmediaset
>
> backupset
>
> restorefile
>
> restorefilegroup
>
> restorehistory

Comment: The msdb database doesn't have indexes on the system tables, so if you had many backup/restore operations over time, purging records might take long. I don't know how to see the records to delete beforehand, but you can try creating indexes as suggested in the following post and doing your purge in batches (with very old dates first, then closer to last 6 months). https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/geoffh/2008/01/21/msdb-performance-tuning/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My gripes with this proc go back a long way:

- [The Annals of Hilariously Bad Code, Part 1: Critique the Code](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/the-annals-of-hilariously-bad-code-part-1/)
- [The Annals of Hilariously Bad Code, Part 2](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/annals-hilariously-bad-code-part-2/)

The problem you run into when deleting large amounts of data is the crappy estimate you get from the table variables.

I've had pretty good luck creating a new version of the proc using temp tables. You could also try just adding recompile hints, but hey, this way we get useful indexes.

As a side note: if you still run into this blocking because this is running long, you can try either removing the transaction code, or changing it to encapsulate each individual delete (though at that point the benefits are negligible).

```
CREATE   PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_delete_backuphistory_pro]
   @oldest_date datetime
 AS
 BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   CREATE TABLE #backup_set_id      (backup_set_id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
   CREATE TABLE #media_set_id       (media_set_id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
   CREATE TABLE #restore_history_id (restore_history_id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)

   INSERT INTO #backup_set_id WITH (TABLOCKX) (backup_set_id)
   SELECT DISTINCT backup_set_id
   FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
   WHERE backup_finish_date < @oldest_date

   INSERT INTO #media_set_id WITH (TABLOCKX) (media_set_id)
   SELECT DISTINCT media_set_id
   FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
   WHERE backup_finish_date < @oldest_date

   INSERT INTO #restore_history_id WITH (TABLOCKX) (restore_history_id)
   SELECT DISTINCT restore_history_id
   FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory
   WHERE backup_set_id IN (SELECT backup_set_id
                           FROM   #backup_set_id)

   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.backupfile
   WHERE backup_set_id IN (SELECT backup_set_id
                           FROM   #backup_set_id)
   IF (@@error > 0)
     GOTO Quit

   DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.backupfilegroup
   WHERE backup_set_id IN (SELECT backup_set_id
                           FROM   #backup_set_id)
   IF (@@error > 0)
     GOTO Quit

   DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.restorefile
   WHERE restore_history_id IN (SELECT restore_history_id
                                FROM   #restore_history_id)
   IF (@@error > 0)
     GOTO Quit

   DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.restorefilegroup
   WHERE restore_history_id IN (SELECT restore_history_id
                                FROM   #restore_history_id)
   IF (@@error > 0)
     GOTO Quit

   DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory
   WHERE restore_history_id IN (SELECT restore_history_id
                                FROM   #restore_history_id)
   IF (@@error > 0)
     GOTO Quit

   DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
   WHERE backup_set_id IN (SELECT backup_set_id
                           FROM   #backup_set_id)
   IF (@@error > 0)
     GOTO Quit

   DELETE msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily
   FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
   WHERE bmf.media_set_id IN (SELECT media_set_id
                              FROM   #media_set_id)
     AND ((SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
           WHERE media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id) = 0)
   IF (@@error > 0)
     GOTO Quit

   DELETE msdb.dbo.backupmediaset
   FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediaset bms
   WHERE bms.media_set_id IN (SELECT media_set_id
                              FROM   #media_set_id)
     AND ((SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
           WHERE media_set_id = bms.media_set_id) = 0)
   IF (@@error > 0)
     GOTO Quit

   COMMIT TRANSACTION
   RETURN

 Quit:
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you could try.

- Restore a backup of your `MSDB` database to a test server and call it
  something like `MSDB_TEST`.
- Once restored, go into the `sp_delete_backuphistory` stored procedure
  in the `MSDB_TEST` database and search/replace `msdb.` with
  `msdb_test.` and alter it.
- Capture the current row count of the tables you are interested in.
- Now, run the *altered* version of the `sp_delete_backuphistory` stored procedure in the `MSDB_TEST` database.
- Compare the current row counts to the previously capture ones.

Answer (score 0):

I created this script which can be used to clear data in small batches which was effective for me - and allows you to keep using the supported `sp_delete_backuphistory`.

[My Blog Post](https://wisedataman.com/removing-large-backup-history-with-sp_delete_backuphistory)

```sql
/********************* Params *******************/
DECLARE @RetentionDays INT = 30 /* How long should we keep the data for in days */
DECLARE @Mins INT = 60 /* Delete data X minutes at a time.  Small interval keeps transaction short.  Less blocking and log usage*/
DECLARE @MaxRuntimeMins INT = 60 /* Stop processing if runtime exceeds this threshold */
/************************************************/

DECLARE @TargetDate DATETIME
DECLARE @oldest_date DATETIME
DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @t1 DATETIME
DECLARE @Duration INT
DECLARE @TotalDuration BIGINT=0
DECLARE @IterationCount INT=0
DECLARE @StopAt DATETIME

/* The target date we want to get to based on the specified @RetentionDays */
SET @TargetDate = DATEADD(dd,-@RetentionDays,GETDATE())
/* When should we stop processing batches based on @MaxRuntimeMins */
SET @StopAt = DATEADD(mi,@MaxRuntimeMins,GETDATE())

/* Get the oldest backup finish date from table.  We will start removing data older than this point + @Mins minutes */
SELECT @oldest_date =  MIN(backup_finish_date)
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset

PRINT CONCAT('Oldest Date: ',@oldest_date)
PRINT CONCAT('Target Date: ', @TargetDate)
PRINT CONCAT('Max Run Time (Mins): ',@MaxRuntimeMins,', Processing will stop after ',@StopAt)

/* Process the delete operation in small chunks until we reach the target date for our retention */
 WHILE 1=1
 BEGIN
    /* Increment date by @Mins minutes */
    SET @oldest_date = DATEADD(mi,@Mins,@oldest_date)
    /* Ensure that we don't overshoot our target date */
    IF @oldest_date > @TargetDate
        SET @oldest_date = @TargetDate  
        
    SET @IterationCount = @IterationCount + 1
    /* 
    Print message using RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT so message is printed immediately.  
    For keeping track of progress 
    */
    SET @Message = CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),114),' Start iteration ',@IterationCount,': Removing backup history before ',@oldest_date)
    RAISERROR(@Message,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    SET @t1 = SYSUTCDATETIME()
    /* Remove the history up to @oldest_date (@Mins minutes worth of history) */
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_backuphistory @oldest_date = @oldest_date;

    /* Print how long this iteration took &amp; keep track of total duration and iteration count */
    SET @Duration = DATEDIFF(ms,@t1,SYSUTCDATETIME())
    SET @TotalDuration = @TotalDuration +  @Duration 
    SET @Message = CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),114),' Iteration ', @IterationCount,' completed in (hh:mi:ss:mmm): ',CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(ms,@Duration,0),114))
    
    RAISERROR(@Message,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

    /* Stop once we hit our target date for retention or we have ran for longer than @MaxRuntimeMins */
    IF @oldest_date>=@TargetDate 
        OR GETDATE() > @StopAt
        BREAK

 END

 /* 
    Print overall stats 
    Accounting for possibility that total duration could span > 1 day
 */
SET @Message = CONCAT('Completed ',
                @IterationCount,
                ' iterations in ',
                CAST(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(d,0,DATEADD(s,@TotalDuration/1000,0)),0) AS NVARCHAR(4000)) + ' Days ',
                LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(s,@TotalDuration/1000,0),114),8),
                ' (hh:mi:ss), Avg Duration: '
                ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(ms,@TotalDuration/NULLIF(@IterationCount,0),0),114), 
                ' (hh:mi:ss:mmm). Reached target date: ',CASE WHEN @oldest_date>=@TargetDate THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END )

RAISERROR(@Message,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
```